# full duplex client-server socket using threads

Tags: c, sockets, pthreads

I need to have a two-way (full duplex) link (where I can simultaneously send and receive data) between a server and a client. With the research that I did, I found out that the best way is to have two threads each implementing a socket between the client and the server. Has anyone got any idea of how to approach this or has seen some similar code that does this? I'm really new to this area and would really welcome any suggestions...

Comment: All sockets are fully duplex, they can both send and receive simultaneously.

Comment: I don't know where you researched, but stop researching there.

Comment: Yes, but when for example the server is listening on the socket and does not receive anything, it cannot it cannot at the same time send to the client (for the case of blocking socket). right?

Comment: Then make the socket non-blocking? Or use system calls such as [`select`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) to poll for input?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two sockets for full duplex communication, unless you are using a higher level transport protocol that is limiting your ability to do simultaneous sends and receives.

One example of such a transport limitation would be if your server is really an HTTP server. Then, if you need bi-directional communication with your application using HTTP, you may need one connection that is performing a GET, and another connection that is performing a PUT.

Otherwise, your client is able to read and write to the same socket simultaneously. You can create 2 threads, where one is reading, and the other is writing, but they would each be operating on the same socket.

Your server could use a similar strategy (a pair of threads per connection), but if the server is handling many connection (say thousands), then you may face scalability issues. Typically, this is solved using non-blocking I/O with some high performance connection multiplexer, like `epoll()` or `kqueue()`, and you only create as many threads as you have cores to distribute the connection processing load. Check out [The C10K Problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) for a good source of information on how to implement highly scalable servers.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do you know of an example code that defines two different threads for reading and writing? As I said I'm really new to this whole concept of sockets and threads...Also here I don't have the scalability issue since there is only one client and server talking, so I don't want to get involved with non-blocking complexity. Thanks!

Comment: Also I just need to send some basic text between the two (not anything complicated like HTTP)

Comment: Ideone doesn't let me create threaded applications, but you can still see the program I wrote: http://ideone.com/K2GgZv

Comment: Thanks a lot man, this really helps... So this is the program for the client side and I need to write something similar for the Server, right?

Comment: It is a simple test program that tests both a client and a server talking to each other. Try to compile it an run it.

Comment: Thanks again for this sample code, I was able to compile and run it. so I just had one question. Since I want to have two separate source files one for the client and one for the server, each being executed in a separate terminal, would it be right to do the following: in the main file (say for example of the client.c file) first create a socket(), then create two pthreads, one calling the read function and the other calling the write function. Also do something similar for the server.c file.  I assume with this setting I do not need to do a fork(). Could you please confirm this?

Comment: You should be able to do what you want that way, go ahead and try. If you run into problems, you can look here to see if stackoverflow already has an answer, and if not, you can ask a new question.

Comment: I was able to do this. Anyone who is interested please let me know so I share the source files...

Comment: Hi again, I had a question regarding the pthread_join function in your code. I've extended the reader() and writer() functions to do reads and writes inside a for(;;) loop i.e. always communicating data between client and server until stopped by the user. I observed that if I don't use the pthread_join functions, that's not doable and   both reader and writer threads return without asking anything on the I/O. I wanted to know what is the role of the pthread_join() functions that make this work correctly?

Comment: @user2225868: The `pthread_join()` is being used by the main thread to wait for the reader and writer threads to finish. If you don't do this, the main thread will exit, and the program will end, perhaps without even letting the reader and writer threads run at all. I believe I have already provided sufficient answers for your posted question. If you have other questions, you can ask new ones.

Comment: What about socketpair? Does it use 2 sockets or 1? If it uses 2, why?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: If you have not yet answered your own question, the answer is the same reason `pipe()` returns two file descriptors.

Comment: @jxh So you're saying socketpair returns 2 because one is for reading and one is for writing?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: Yes, except for sockets, it is bidirectional. So whichever one is written to, the other one is used to read from.

Comment: If a single socket can be bidirectional, then what's the point of using a socketpair (2 sockets) to get bidirectional communication?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: I'm just going to let you think about it. But, you are free to post your own question if you cannot figure it out.